# How was I able to continue reviewing even after I hit the 20 reviews limit?

Tags: support, review-queues

There is a maximum of 20 reviews per day. How was I able to go over the limit? Even after I hit the 20 reviews limit I was able to continue reviewing in the queue.

[image: maximum 20]

---

[image: 1.5K elements late answer]

Comment: @Louis I don't belive [22 reviews](http://screencloud.net/v/v6I3) and users with 40 reviews

Comment: @Louis In queues reviews exists a maximum of 20 reviews ... how it is possible, we can overcome this limit ?

Comment: @Louis The problem was fixed [Thank you for reviewing 20 late answers today](http://screencloud.net/v/6RM5) ..... but now I have [30 reviews and many users has 40 reviews](http://screencloud.net/v/oyb2)

Comment: Are you saying you were still *able* to go into the queue and continue reviewing even *after* you got more than 20 reviews??

Comment: @Louis yes It was possible for a short time .... I cannot do this now

Comment: Once a queue hits 1000 items up for review, the review limit bumps to 40 per day. The Late Answer queue hit the 1000 mark, so eveyone got 40 reviews for the queue. Give me a minute and I'll find a source to verify that.

Comment: @Kendra I did not know .... thanks

Comment: Found that source! This is covered in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/266735) over on MSE. I don't think there's a dupe for this on MSO yet, after a couple searches, so if it gets reopened here soon I'll post that as an answer so we have it documented should something like this happen again.

Comment: @Louis Is possible reopen question?, kendra post the answer

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The reason that, at least temporarily, users were getting a max 40 reviews in the Late Answer queue is that, as the result of [a change in the criteria to enter the queue,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) there were more than 1000 items in the Late Answer queue.

This is explained in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900) on MSE. To quote the relevant section:

> ### Reviewing
>
> - [20 reviews per queue per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981) if the queue size is less than 1000 (150 on Stack Overflow)
> - [40 reviews per queue per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152233) if the queue size is 1000 or more  (150 on Stack Overflow)
> - No review limit for ♦ mods

So once the queue is below 150 items once more (and I believe it already is) reviews will once again be limited to 20 per user per day.

Comment: What's interesting is that this is *only while* the queue is over 1000. I had assumed it was some kind of "if the queue is at 1000 or more when your reviews roll over, you get 40", but this is very clearly not the case.

Comment: I remember reading about review limits somewhere and thinking it was associated with rep or total reviews in the associated queue. I was so confused when I hit 40, so this is good to know.